# How to change overlapping of axis caption in graphs?

Tags: pgfplots

I have plotted a data in latex using pgfplots. The axis caption of the graph are overlapping eachother. Can someone tell me how to change it. My code is as follows: I have attached the image file please have a look.[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}  

\begin{filecontents*}{SU.csv}
m0FEED AT773.15K  AT823.15K  AT873.15K  AT923.15K  AT973.15K
0.075   0.495843488 0.687975654 0.802758364 0.865453157 0.90095418
0.08    0.433275958 0.63711497  0.764762765 0.836415754 0.877853296
0.085   0.377703882 0.58877211  0.72713628  0.806800884 0.853747587
0.09    0.329859463 0.543553705 0.690492516 0.777167037 0.829117316
0.095   0.289232247 0.501783735 0.655238529 0.747938237 0.80435735
0.1     0.25512825  0.463554416 0.621668998 0.719419939 0.779776678
0.105   0.226695537 0.428822603 0.58988815  0.69182388  0.755609267
0.11    0.203047122 0.397428339 0.559967523 0.665288195 0.732022125
0.115   0.183347426 0.369147831 0.531913494 0.639878649 0.70913488
0.12    0.166854273 0.343723694 0.505677274 0.615644454 0.687021728
0.125   0.152951994 0.320885099 0.481189821 0.592587395 0.665727233
0.13    0.141135569 0.300364425 0.458362007 0.570690758 0.6423695
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\pgfplotstableread{SU.csv}{\table}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[grid=major,legend style={nodes={scale=0.5, transform shape}},legend pos=north east, minor tick num=1,
xlabel=Feed flow rate (\si{mol/s}), ylabel = Steam utilisation (\%), legend entries={AT773.15K, AT823.15K, AT873.15K, AT923.15K, AT973.15K}]
\addplot [black,mark=square] table [x=m0FEED, y=AT773.15K]\table;
\addplot [red,mark=*] table [x=m0FEED, y=AT823.15K]\table;
\addplot [blue,mark=triangle] table [x=m0FEED, y=AT873.15K] \table;
\addplot [green,mark=diamond] table [x=m0FEED, y=AT923.15K] \table;
\addplot [orange,mark=x] table [x=m0FEED, y=AT973.15K] \table;
\legend{AT773.15K, AT823.15K, AT873.15K, AT923.15K, AT973.15K}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable. You insert a image on the wrong place, also are missed `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` etc.

Comment: Sorry I have reedited it thank you.

Comment: I think adding `x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2,/tikz/.cd,}` to the `axis` options helps, right?

Comment: Sorry, but your code is still not compilable. Please test it before you publish in question. Help us to help you!

Comment: Sorry again I have rechecked it now the code works. On the x axis you can see the overlap of the numbers

Comment: @VISHNU, have you tested my suggestion?

Comment: yes i have tested but its not working @StefanPinnow

Comment: @VISHNU, interesting. Tested it (again) and it works perfectly fine. Did the result change when you added the suggestion?

Comment: @StefanPinnow I tested it, it worked thank you so much